# error with index when we group two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have made the following code:

```
df_Pred_2['difference_days'] = df_Pred_2.groupby(['customer','product']).Date.apply(lambda x: x.diff()).dt.days
```

i get this error:

> incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

What could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide input data ? please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your `groupby` operation very likely reduces the number of rows, hence the resulting series has less rows than `df_Pred_2` and as such, the index cannot match. You could try assigning the result to a dataframe that has already been grouped on the same columns.

Comment: hm, try adding ```.reset_index(drop=True)``` at the very end of you snippet. Or you might wanna try ```df_Pred_2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)``` before running your ```groupby``` operation

Answer (score 0):

**Likely cause for the problem**

Without assigning it, ask the output of

> df_Pred_2.groupby(['customer','product']).Date.apply(lambda x: x.diff()).dt.days

Provided the operation works (which we cannot verify until you post some representative input data), you will notice that [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) likely returns a dataframe with different shape and index, one that cannot be assigned back into the input dataframe, as you are trying to do with:

> df_Pred_2['difference_days'] = ...

**A solution**

Either assign it without column selection

> df_Pred_2 = ...

or (even better?) assign to a new dataframe!